# Enter key behaviour Angular and Material form

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, material-ui

In my forms in a MEAN application I have:

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="thesisForm"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" (keydown.shift.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
```

I do this because occasionally people press enter without wanting to submit the form. So to avoid accidents I add the prevent default.

BUT this results in text areas not reacting to the <kbd>enter</kbd> key and I cannot introduce line spaces. If I write the text and copy paste it I can add the new lines, but not when pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> . How can I fix this so that I can use the text area normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave `preventDefault()` on form element, and add `(keydown.enter)="$event.stopPropagation()"` on particular element (like textarea) and hitting enter there won't trigger a submit, and will allow new line in multi-line inputs.